# SPARQL count item in an intersection

Tags: sparql, rdf

Given the following triples

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@base <http://example.com/> .



<person1> ex:has_interpretation <interpretation1> .
<interpretation1> ex:refers_to <objectA> ;
 ex:resultIn <X> .

<person2> ex:has_interpretation <interpretation2> .
<interpretation2> ex:refers_to <objectA> ;
 ex:resultIn <Y> .

<person2> ex:has_interpretation <interpretation3> .
<interpretation3> ex:refers_to <objectB> ;
 ex:resultIn <Z> .

<person3> ex:has_interpretation <interpretation4> .
<interpretation3> ex:refers_to <objectA> ;
 ex:resultIn <ZZ> .
```

I am trying to use SPARQL to:

1. count only the number of object referred to by an interpretation by both person1 and person2 (intersection)
2. count the number of distinct interpretations over the object
3. count the number of object **not** referred to by an interpretation by both person1 and person2
4. having the above count together with a list of objects referred to by an interpretation and the people who create the interpretation.

I am having trouble specifically with 1 (and consequently, 3), as I cannot find a way to count the intersection of the interpreted objects.

My current SPARQL query which does not obtain what I want:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>

SELECT ?person (COUNT(distinct ?object) as ?c_object) (group_concat(distinct ?interpretation;separator="; ") as ?interpretations)

WHERE {

  ?person ex:has_interpretation ?interpretation .
 ?interpretation 
      ex:refers_to ?object ;
       ex:resultIn ?result .


FILTER (?person = <http://example.com/person1> || ?person = <http://example.com/person2> )
 
}
GROUP BY ?person ?object
```

What instead I would like is just:

| object_uri | number_object | interpretations | person_involved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<objectA>` | 1 | `<interpretation1>,<interpretation2>` | `<person1>,<person2>` |

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you grouping by `?person` if you want a list of persons per object? Also, is the `number_object` value larger than 1 in which case exactly?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. count only the number of object referred to by an interpretation by both person1 and person2 (intersection)

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
    
SELECT DISTINCT ?obj
WHERE { 
    <http://example.com/person1> ex:has_interpretation/ex:refers_to ?obj .
    <http://example.com/person2> ex:has_interpretation/ex:refers_to ?obj .
}
```

Here the query matches only those objects (`?obj`) which have  `ex:has_interpretation/ex:refers_to` paths to them from *both* `<person1>` and `<person2>`.

> 2. count the number of distinct interpretations over the object

Just use the `COUNT()` function as the paths used in the answer for 1. above are distinct (different):

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
    
SELECT DISTINCT ?obj
WHERE { 
    <http://example.com/person1> ex:has_interpretation/ex:refers_to ?obj .
    <http://example.com/person2> ex:has_interpretation/ex:refers_to ?obj .
}
```

> 3. count the number of object not referred to by an interpretation by both person1 and person2

You *might* be able to find a fancy way to query for this but I would just count distinct objects:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?obj
WHERE { 
    ?x ex:refers_to ?obj .
}
```

...and then subtract the results from 1. above. This is easy to understand and you've already got the results from 1. to work with.